# The relationship between subfields and subgroups of a finite field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, finite-fields

I am trying to get my head around the structure $GF(p^n)$ when viewed as a vector space of dimension $n$ over $GF(p)$ (mainly the relationship between the additive and multiplicative structures). I'm unsure about a few things:

1) If $m\mid n$, and $k$ is a multiple of $m$ not dividing $n$, how many subspaces of dimension $k$ (amongst $\prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{(p^n-p^i)}{(p^k-p^i)}$ of them) contain the unique subfield $GF(p^m)$? Moreover, are these "special" subspaces fixed under multiplication from $GF(p^m)$? I'm specifically interested in the size of the stabiliser of such a subspace under the action of the full multiplicative group.

2) Is it true that if gcd(m,n)=1, then no subspace of dimension $m$ can contain a subfield? (excluding the case m=1, of course)

3) If a subspace does not contain a subfield, must it have a trivial stabiliser under the action of the multiplicative group? i.e. are the subspaces partitioned into orbits of maximal size? $\bf{EDIT}$: not trivial stabiliser (obviously false), but stabilised by nothing more than $GF(p)^*$?

Any words of wisdom on techniques to deal with these kinds of questions would be greatly appreciated. If it makes any difference, I'm mainly interested in the case $p=2$.

Comment: Have you tried working through any examples with small values of $m,n,k$?

Comment: The overall moral I can suggest is this: when viewed solely as a vector space, $GF(p^n)$ completely forgets about any field structure (forgets about multiplication, other than by the scalars in $GF(p)$). So the number of subspaces of dimension $k$ that contain $GF(p^m)$ is exactly the same as the number of subspaces of dimension $k$ that contain any random subspace of dimension $m$, regardless of whether $m\mid k$. Similarly, 2) is false: you can start wish a subfield of dimension less than $m$, consider it just as a subspace, and extend it to a subspace of dimension $m$ in all kinds of ways.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, yes; but for the case $p=2$ and for odd $n\geq 3$, so quite specific. In which case the first $n$ that isn't prime is $9$, and that's already quite a large field. The reason behind these cases is that I'm interested in the Suzuki simple groups (and these subgroups turn up). I'll play around with some smaller examples.

Comment: @GregMartin, thanks. I guess I should have pointed out that my main motivation behind viewing $GF(p^n)$ as a vector space is try to gain some vague geometric intuition behind what is going on in finite fields. But I definitely don't want to neglect the underlying field structure! So there's still something special about the subspaces which are also subfields in their own right.

Comment: I agree that they are special - but special with respect to the field multiplication, not special with respect to the vector space structure. As my comment describes....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 1) can be reformulated in the following way: Given a finite field $F$ and a finite dimensional vector space $V$ with a subspace $V_0 \subseteq V$ of dimension $m$, how many subspaces of $V$ of dimension $k$ contain $V_0$? 
We are thus looking for the subspaces of $V/V_0$ of dimension $k-m$.
Given that $V$ has dimension $n$, the question reduces to the problem of computing the number of $k-m$ dimensional subspaces of an $n-m$ dimensional $F$-vector space (which you already seem to know).
Note that your assumption on $k$ is not necessary to do this.

To be stable under multiplication with $GF(p^m)$ theses subspaces would have to be $GF(p^m)$-subspaces of $GF(p^n)$ and here your assumption on $k$ to be a multiple of $m$ is clearly necessary for this to happen (I don't see why you would want $k$ not to divide $n$).
Indeed any $GF(p^m)$-subspace of $GF(p^n)$ containing $GF(p^m)$ with dimension $\frac{k}{m}$ defines a $GF(p)$-subspace containing $GF(p^m)$ with dimension $k$. 
The converse however does not hold.

For 2) there are easy counterexamples. You can take any three dimensional $GF(p)$-subspace containing $GF(p^2)$ in $GF(p^4)$.

For 3) note that any subspace is stabilized by the multiplicative group of $GF(p)$ so there will be no trivial stabilizers.

**Edit:**

Asking for the stabilizer of a $GF(p)$-subspace of $GF(p^n)$ under the action of $GF(p^n)^*$ has not much to do with containing certain subfields. In fact if $m$ divides $n$ then we find a direct sum decomposition $GF(p^n) = GF(p^m) \oplus V_0$ for some $GF(p^m)$-subspace $V_0$ of $GF(p^n)$. As $1$ is not an element of $V_0$, it contains no subfield of $GF(p^n)$. However the stabilizer of $V_0$ will contain $GF(p^m)^*$.

In fact, the subfield of $GF(p^n)$ generated by the stabilizer of some subspace $V_0$ will be the largest subfield of $GF(p^n)$ such that $V_0$ is a vector space over this field and the stabilizer is then this field's multiplicative group.

Comment: Thanks, this is enlightening. You're right about the unnecessary assumption of $k$ not dividing $n$, I was just mentally distinguishing between families of subspaces of dimension $k$ amongst which there are no subfields of $GF(p^n)$, but this is rather silly in hindsight. Ah, of course, I was already aware of plenty of counter examples to 3)! But in characteristic 2 the question still holds ;)

Answer (score 1):

Take $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$, and suppose that $m | n$, say $n = mc$.  Then we can view $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ as a $c$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}$. If you think of $k$ being a multiple of $m$ as well, then you can put $k = m d$, so $d \leq c$, and you can ask how many $d$-dimensional subspaces you have of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}^{c}$; this gives the number of subspaces of dimension $k$ in $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{n}$ which are fixed under multiplication by elements of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}$.  If we want the number containing $\mathbb{F}_{p^m}$, (embedded as a one-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}^{c}$), this is equal to the number of $d-1$ dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{F}_{p^{m}}^{c-1}$.